# Read all available data from SSL-Socket

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, boost-asio

I am using a `boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>` as receiving socket. I know that the underlying socket has available bytes to be read, and I know how many. I now want to read all available data through the SSL-Socket using either `boost::asio::read` or some read function from the socket.

I tried using `boost::asio::read` with `transfer_all()` as CompletionCondition, however that will block until the client closes the connection.

I also cannot use `transfer_exactly(n)` as CompletionCondition since I do not know how many *unencrypted* bytes I can read from the socket.

Can I find out how many bytes I can read from the encrypted socket or is there maybe even a simpler way to read all available data?

Comment: Why? Your application protocol won't consist of 'message == all available data'. It must define or delimit its messages somehow.

Comment: Call the `ssl::stream` method [async_read_some](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream/async_read_some.html) with a [mutable buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/mutable_buffer.html) and a [ReadHandler](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ReadHandler.html) callback function.